# reading 128-bit encrypted word 2007 file in objective-c / iphone

Tags: objective-c, iphone, encryption, ms-word, aes

I want to read a word 2007 docx file which is 128-bit encrypted, using objective-c and i have any idea the way I should follow.

Is it possible decrypting the file and if it is, how can I read the docx?

Answer (score 0):

This is probably more an objective C question than a word question.

Word DOCX files are essentially just ZIP archives that have a DOCX extension.

Save a DOCX file, give it a password, then rename the DOCX file as a ZIP, and you should be able to open it with any old zip manager, provided you have the password. I'm betting there are objective-c zip archive handling code snips out there somewhere.

As for the second question about reading the docx,

Well, once you have the zip opened and unencrypted, the zip is just that, a zip archive of a bunch of files. The files depict individual elements of the docx file.

You can get a start on the specs from the wikipedia article

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Office_Open_XML

But really, just rename a docx as zip, unzip it somewhere and this start poking around.

Most of the contents are XML files, that can be read in a variety of different ways (DOM, SAX, plain ol' line input, etc).